# Literature on Kripke models

Tags: lo.logic, modal-logic

Which is the best introduction to Kripke-models for modal logics?
I am a M.Sc in mathematics and know predicatlogic.

Comment: The textbook on modal logic by Chagrov and Zakharyaschev, and the one by Blackburn, De Rijke, and Venema, contain a lot of introductory material on Kripke models, but neither is specifically focused on Kripke models.

Comment: You can see also an introductory exposition for Modal Logic into : James Garson, [Modal Logic for Philosophers](https://books.google.it/books?id=rFpbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA57) (2nd ed, 2013).

Comment: Reagrding Intuitionistic Logic, you can see ; Anne Troelstra & Dirk van Dalen,  [Constructivism in mathematics : An Introduction. Volume 1](https://books.google.it/books?id=-tc2qp0-2bsC&pg=PA76) (1988).

Comment: May also be useful : John Burgess, [Philosophical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=k32w3_wjBoYC&pg=PA41) (2009).

Comment: Maybe also *Appendix A: Models* of John Burgess, [Kripke](https://books.google.it/books?id=YS9_Oz-JZJUC&printsec=frontcover) (2012).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: Thank you for these references. I actually need to know about Kripke models for a philosphy course I am attending on reference and acquintance so presumably both Garson and Burgess would be appropriate reading material. That is given the time...

Comment: Just a caveat. The notion of Kripke semantics as introduced by Kripke himself is not equal to the one commonly used in logic and topos theory. Indeed, the notion of Kripke semantics precedes the notion of forcing as noted in the comments of my question that was tagged in the answer below, however the notion commonly used nowadays was not available (or at least not widely known) when Cohen created the notion of forcing.

Answer (score 3):

Brian F. Chellas: *Modal Logic: An Introduction*, 1980.

Starts very basic but covers in detail the beautiful completeness theorem proofs for the basic systems like $S5$, $S4$, $K$.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that this is the 'best' introduction to Kripke models (as 'best' is always a relative term), but John P. Burgess's survey article "Kripke Models" presumes only knowledge of propositional and predicate logic.  It can be found in Alan Berger (ed.), [*Saul Kripke*](https://books.google.it/books?id=fFsb0zfe6PoC&pg=PA119), Cambridge University Press (2011), or on the Web at www.gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c626/reports.Kripke1.pdf .  It covers most basic applications of Kripke models to modal logic adequately except for the application of Kripke models to forcing.  A nice introduction to that topic might be the references in the comments and answer to the mathoverflow question, "Forcing is Intuitionistic".  Also the Wikipedia entry, "Kripke Semantics".

Comment: Thank you for this reference, (the link worked fine) which seems to be to the point for me.

Comment: @AndersGöransson:  Glad you found this reference helpful.  The complete article is at www.gauss.ececs.uc.edu/.... , as referenced above.

Comment: I got the article downloaded straight away from the link you provided. It seems to cover all that I hoped for.